# How to install CUDA 8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, cuda

Ubuntu 18.04 TLS has moved to CUDA 9.1 now, which deprecates the Nvidia Fermi Architecture.

I have tried installing the cuda 8 toolkit from nvidia with an `--override` option (to discard compiler verification) butthe installation failed as follows:

**Command**: `sudo ./cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run --override --toolkitpath /usr/local/cuda-8.0/`

**Output**:

```
You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue?
(y)es/(n)o [ default is no ]: y

Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 375.26?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: n

Install the CUDA 8.0 Toolkit?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

Enter Toolkit Location
 [ default is /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ]: /usr/local/cuda-8.0

Do you want to install a symbolic link at /usr/local/cuda?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

Install the CUDA 8.0 Samples?
(y)es/(n)o/(q)uit: y

Enter CUDA Samples Location
 [ default is /home/user ]: 

Installing the CUDA Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-8.0 ...
Warning: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-8.0. Use --toolkitpath to specify the toolkit location.
Installing the CUDA Samples in /home/user ...
sh: 1: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/cuda-install-samples-8.0.sh: not found
chown: cannot access '/home/user/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples': No such file or directory

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed
Samples:  Installation Failed
```

Comment: Apparently, you need to specify the toolkit location using option `--toolkitpath`.

Comment: I have already tried. Added my command in the post.

Comment: Actually, you don't need that option, since you're installing in the default directory. Have you uninstalled any previous version of Cuda Toolkit?

Comment: I have tried without the option `--toolkitpath`, and I was getting the same error. Indeed, I have installed the default nvidia-cuda-toolkit 9.1 from the ubuntu 18.04 repos. But I removed it after realizing my architecture was deprecated.

Comment: Make sure that there are no files remaining from the cuda 9.1 installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the issue using the following procedure:

1. unpack .run file using the command: `./cuda*.run --tar mxvf` (or `sh ./cuda*.run --tar mxvf`)
2. copy unpacked file InstallUtils.pm to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
3. enter command in terminal: `export $PERL5LIB`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cleaner ways to solve this issue:

1. Set current directory as perl library search path by: `PERL5LIB=. sh cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run your-other-options`. Related [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/968656/cuda-8-0-on-debian/).
2. Install the missing perl module by: `sudo apt install module-install-perl`. Related [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/983777/cuda-setup-and-installation/can-t-locate-installutils-pm-in-inc/post/5261224/#5261224)